# cat to combine heredoc and file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cat

I'm trying to and failing to understand why this doesn't work. I'm trying to use `cat` to combine an existing file and a heredoc into one file:

```
# test.txt
Hi there
```

```
$ cat test.txt <<END > /tmp/combined.txt
This is heredoc
END
```

I would have expected this to function in essence like:

```
cat file.txt file1.txt > /tmp/combined.txt
```

But what I actually see is just the contents of `test.txt`:

```
#/tmp/combined.txt
Hi there
```

If I do just the heredoc it works. If i do just the file it works obviously. What is it about combining them that makes cat ignore the heredoc?

(I know I can use `tee` and a variety of other approaches to do this but I want to fill in my understanding of cat, redirection etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` echos the contents of its input filename arguments *or* standard input (which is where the text of a heredoc is made available to be read) if none are given, but not both. However, if one of the arguments is `-`, that one is treated as reading from standard input:

```bash
$ cat test.txt - <<EOF
This is heredoc
EOF
Hi there
This is heredoc
```

Comment: @move_slow_break_things : It's not. A heredoc is equivalent to stdin. It is the `-` which tricks cat into using the standard input in place of a file.